# L2TP over IPSec VPN on Fedora 21

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, l2tp

I need to connect a Linux Fedora 21 desktop to a L2TP over IPSec VPN. I was given a set of instructions for how to do so on a MAC as that is what they use but I have been unable to do so on Fedora. Here are the instructions I was given:

1. Open System Preferences
2. In the bottom left pane, click the +
3. Select VPN as the interface type
4. Select L2TP over IPSec as the VPN Type
5. Set the service name to "Some company name"
6. Set the server address to: x.x.x.x
7. Account Name: xxxusername
8. Password: xxxpassword
9. Shared secret: xxxsharedsecret

Now I've searched a bunch for this but nothing I have tried has worked yet.

In particular I have the following package installed via yum:

```
NetworkManager-l2tp.x86_64
```

In the Network Manager GUI I created the VPN connection via:

1. Add Network Connection
2. VPN
3. L2TP...
4. Settings:

   1. Name: "Some company name"
   2. Gateway: x.x.x.x
   3. Username: xxxusername
   4. Password: xxxpassword
   5. NT Domain: blank
   6. Firewall Zone: Default
   7. Not available to other users
5. Then IPSec Settings:

   1. Checked Enable IPSec...
   2. Group Name: "Some company name"
   3. Gateway Id: blank
   4. pre-shared key: xxxsharedkey

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and why I can't connect? One thing to note which I don't think is a problem is the company name string does have a space in it.

Double props to whomever has a solution which allows me to connect that's just via the command line/editing text files as well.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or repeat notifications?  What happens if you change the settings to allow for all users?

Comment: This seems like a very detailed guide : [L2TP/IPSec VPN client on Fedora](https://www.moucha.cc/charon/l2tpipsec-vpn-client-on-fedora/) and is even pretty recent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very detailed cookbook guide in this article : [L2TP/IPSec VPN client on Fedora](https://www.moucha.cc/charon/l2tpipsec-vpn-client-on-fedora/).
It is even pretty recent, from October 1, 2014.

It lists the packages to install :

```
libreswan
xl2tpd
```

And the files that require editing :

```
/etc/ipsec.d/desired_vpn_name.conf
/etc/ipsec.d/desired_vpn_name.secrets
/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf
/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd.VPN_CONNECTION_NAME
/var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
```

<sub>(The article is pretty much to the point, so no reason to reproduce it here entirely.)</sub>

Comment: I had previously seen this but it turns out I had made some errors. The main being the ipsec.conf file doesn't include the ipsec.d config files by default. I've got it working now.

Comment: For anyone who is reading this and wants to do the same thing here is a script I made that does the above. https://github.com/Mokon/menv/blob/master/bin/ipsec_l2tp_vpn

I gladly accept pull requests that improve the script...

Answer (score 1):

run the following as root.

```
    cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
    wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:wejaeger/Fedora_16/home:wejaeger.repo
    yum install l2tp-ipsec-vpn
```

Comment: it should work with later versions of Fedora, so dont mind it saying Fedora 16.

Comment: thanks but I had trouble going this route. There was some dependency issues that I never resolved as that repo doesn't contain everything it needs.